# Constructing a D type flip-flop from JK type flip-flops

Tags: digital-logic

How can I construct a D type flip-flop from JK type flip-flops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As per wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#JK_latch), all you need to do is connect `K` to the inverse of `J`.

Doing this effectively removes the possibility of `00` and `11` inputs. If the `J` is treated as `D` then:

- `D` = 1 sets `Q`
- `D` = 0 resets `Q`

This behaviour is then identical to the `D` flip-flop.

For this reason the `JK` flip-flop is called the universal flip-flop, because you can construct all other flip-flop types with it.